# Not able to stream activity logs into Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I'm using free tier Azure account. I'm trying to configure activity logs streaming into Event Hubs as per instructions on page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-stream-activity-logs-event-hubs

I have created a new EventHub, Shared Access Policy called "ActivityLogsPolicy" with Manage, Send and Listen permissions.

I used this policy to configure "Export" from Activity logs however it keeps failing with error message "Create or update activity log profilesFailure"

Has anyone encountered this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it to work as follows:
In order to make it work, you have to “Register” support for a provider called “microsoft.insights” the whole thing has look and feel of “Windows Registries” :pensive:
Search for Subscriptions in all services -> Select your subscription -> Resource Providers -> Search for “microsoft.insights” -> Enable it. Then it works

Comment: Worth noting this needs to be done on the subscription you're going write logs to, not the one the logs are coming from (although in my case  the source subscription had this enabled but the target didn't.) This happens for exporting to storage account as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error after moving a subscription to a new enterprise agreement. I was not able to get it working so I needed to create a new subscription.